# Choose Highest Numbered File - Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a directory full of .jar files, named progressively like so:

```
 version-1.jar
 version-2.jar
 version-3.jar
```

I am trying to select the highest numbered file. Is there any really simple way to do it?
Because doing `.\version*.jar` causes an error, presumably due to the multiple files?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We need delayed expansion

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Just a variable for the maximum:

```
set max=0
```

Then iterate over the files:

```
for %%x in (version-*.jar) do (
```

We need the file name without extension

```
  set "FN=%%~nx"
```

And remove the `version-` from the start:

```
  set "FN=!FN:version-=!"
```

Now `FN` should contain just the number and we can compare:

```
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
```

And we're done:

```
echo highest version: version-%max%.jar
```

The complete batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for %%x in (version-*.jar) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  set "FN=!FN:version-=!"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
echo highest version: version-%max%.jar
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there a simpler method at all? That seems like a bit overkill-ish

Comment: The problem is that the numbers might be longer than a single digit and then any naïve sorting breaks down.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a slightly simpler version than Joey's code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set max=0
for /f "tokens=1* delims=-.0" %%A in ('dir /b /a-d version-*.jar') do if %%B gtr !max! set max=%%B
echo higest version: version-%max%.jar
```

This code will work even if the version numbers are zero prefixed as long as the version number is never 0 (zero). Specifying tokens=1* with 0 included as a delimiter causes leading zeros to be stripped from the version number while preserving all zeros after the first non-zero digit.

There is a simpler solution if all versions are zero prefixed to a constant width. But this solution works both with and without zero prefixing.

Joey's code will fail if leading zeros are present because that indicates octal notation. Invalid octal digits with leading zeros will be treated as strings causing the comparison to give the wrong result. This is probably not an issue since the original question implies leading zeros are not present. But better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: I did simplify the question somewhat, strictly speaking the numbers range from 4000 to 4100... I was looking for ease of understanding in the answer though xD ive never met delayedexpansion before

Comment: Your use of tokens=1*, %%A and %%B could do with some explanation, but based on your code I was able to adapt the for loop for my needs, great! I also found that a space is always regarded as a delimiter even though not explicitly stated.