# Batch file - recursively find highest numbered file and rename it

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

I've taken the script from here to find the highest numbered file - [Choose Highest Numbered File - Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645226/choose-highest-numbered-file-batch-file)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for %%x in (*-*.png) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  set "FN=!FN:*-=!"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
```

The tricky part is I have many folders that contain numbered files:

```
folderA/fileA-01.png
folderA/fileA-02.png
folderA/fileA-03.png
folderA/fileA-04.png

folderB/fileB-01.png
folderB/fileB-02.png
folderB/fileB-03.png
folderB/fileB-04.png
folderB/fileB-05.png
```

I would like to rename each highest numbered file from each folder to fileA-max.png and fileB-max.png - i.e. instead of the highest number use "max".

I'm not frequently doing batch files and when I do it's usually something very basic and simplistic so if you could - please help me with this one.

Comment: String manipulation reference: http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php

Comment: If the files sort correctly as the samples you have shown then it will be a very simple loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off &setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /d %%a in (*) do (
    for /f "tokens=1*delims=-:" %%b in ('dir /b /a-d /o-n "%%~a"^|findstr /n $') do if %%b==1 (
        for /f "delims=-" %%d in ("%%~nc") do echo(ren "%%~a\%%~c" "%%~d-max%%~xc"
    )
)
```

Comment: Sorry to be a pain - but that doesn't work. I've tried running it from the top directory and from within the specific directory that contains the files, but it still didn't work?

Comment: It works from the folder that contains te subfolders with the files.

Comment: OK. Maybe I'm stupid, but when I removed the echo before the ren it worked, otherwise it just echoed the right thing, but it didn't actually rename the files? Is that how it was supposed to be?