# Batch: Return filename with highest integer

Tags: windows, batch-file, filenames

If I have a directory full of text files such as

```
01.text.sql
02text.sql
3text.sql
```

how would I return the file name with the highest integer e.g. 3.text.sql? As you can see the numbers might not be prefixed with 0 and might be missing a . after the integer. I know I have to loop through the directory with something like this

[Choose Highest Numbered File - Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645226/choose-highest-numbered-file-batch-file)

however, this does not take into account different file name formats. Is there any way a batch script can loop through a directory and automatically pull the file with the highest integer or do I have to store the file names and compare them with each other in a separate loop?

Currently I have something like this but it returns 3text instead of just 3

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET max=0
FOR %%x in (*.sql) DO (
  SET "FN=%%~nx"
  SET "FN=!FN:*-=!"
  IF !FN! GTR !max! SET max=!FN!
)
ECHO Highest script number is %max%
```

Updated loop:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET scriptmax=0
FOR %%x in (*.sql) DO (
  SET "FN=%%~nx"
  SET a=1000!FN!
  SET /A FN=a %% 1000
  IF !FN! GTR !max! SET max=!FN!
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set /A a=b` will interpret everything in `b` up to the first non numeric character as a number, so

```
set FN=03text.txt
set /A a=FN
```

will set `%a%` nicely to `3`. But we have an additional problem here: Numbers prefixed with a `0` will be interpreted as octal, so 08 and 09 are illegal. To fix this:

```
set FN=09text.txt
set t=1!FN!
set /A a=t-100
```

will yield `9`.

However, this will only work if you know how many digits to expect, maybe you have to check for a leading zero first (`if "%FN:~0,1%" == "0" ...`), and/or even chop off leading zeroes (`set FN=%FN:~1%`)

Edit: a better way:

```
set FN=09text.txt
set a=1000!FN!
set /A FN=a %% 1000
```

will work for anything up to 999.

Comment: If you split off the previously prepended digit `1` rather than subtracting `100` then you do not need to know how many digits there are in total...

Comment: @aschipfl: how? i was trying to think of a way, but %a:~1% leaves me with 09 again?

Comment: Remaining leading zeros could be removed with this: `for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%Z in ("%FN:~1%") do set "FN=%%Z" & set /A "FN+=0"`; but it seems you found an even easier solution meanwhile...

Comment: I replaced `SET "FN=!FN:*-=!"` with `SET /A a=1000!FN! %% 1000` but it states I am missing operators? Sorry if I am bad with batch syntax I have not used it before.

Comment: it seems it doesn't work with delayed variables inline. Try `set a=1000!FN!
  set /A FN=a %% 1000
` This works for your examples.

Comment: Unfortunately upon making the change although, you have fixed the syntax errors. It still displays the highest script number as 0. Would it help if show the updated loop and the directory layout in the question?

Comment: Apologies it was an error on my part. Thank you very much for your help.