# Create a copy of the latest file version, and increase version in filename by one in a windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have multiple folders with multiple versioned files in there. For instance filename_v1-xx.xlsx. I'm looking for a way, via batch file, to locate the highest xx number, and create a copy of the file with the filename changed to xx+1.

So if it finds filename_v1-55.xlsx, it needs to create a copy in the same folder called filename_v1-56.xlsx.

I found this: [Choose Highest Numbered File - Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11645226/choose-highest-numbered-file-batch-file) which allows me to find the highest file number, but I can't work out how to create the new file with the new filename.

What I have so far is:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for %%x in (Camera-Data-v1-*.xlsx) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  set "FN=!FN:Camera-Data-v1-=!"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
echo highest version: Camera-Data-v1-%max%.xlsx
set newMax=%max%+1
echo Camera-Data-v1-%newMax%.xlsx
pause
```

This echo's. "highest version: Camera-Data-v1-74.xlsx Camera-Data-v1-74+1.xlsx"

So I think it's the `set newMax=%max%+1` which is wrong, I'm using echo's instead of copy for testing, if the echo says the right filename I will change to be `copy Camera-Data-v1-%max%.xlsx Camera-Data-v1-%newMax%.xlsx`.

The variable number in the filename will always be two characters, sometimes starting with a 0.

Comment: Just my opinion but even if this is not about versioning source code you could consider using a Version Control System instead.

Comment: At first, StackOverflow is not a free code/script writing service, so you have to try it on your own and come back here when you are stuck, providing a [mcve] of your coding attempts. Read also the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Second, you need to clearly specify how the file names and the version numbers therein are assembled, otherwise, one has to guess and might therefore deliver an unsuitable answer...

Comment: `set /A newMax=%max%+1`

Answer (score 1):

Solved, thank you @Aacini works perfectly!

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set max=0
for %%x in (Camera-Data-v1-*.xlsx) do (
  set "FN=%%~nx"
  set "FN=!FN:Camera-Data-v1-=!"
  if !FN! GTR !max! set max=!FN!
)
echo highest version: Camera-Data-v1-%max%.xlsx
set /A newMax=%max%+1
copy Camera-Data-v1-%max%.xlsx Camera-Data-v1-%newMax%.xlsx
pause
```

Comment: Read the help file for the command next time before you post a question. You could have easily solved this yourself.

Comment: Unlike so many first-time posters, at least the OP responded to a request for an MCVE and then learned from that.